# Does Entity Framework's DbContext save changes if no changes were made?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I could not find an answer on the Internet.

Let's suppose I have a `DbContext`, and I just select all the entities from it. I don't add, update or delete any entity on the `DbSet`.

If I call `SaveChanges` afterwards on the `DbSet`. Does it actually waste resources establishing a connection and other stuff even If I did not made any changes to the `DbSet`?

Is it smart enough to detect if a change was made or not, and behave differently?

Comment: Have you tried it using a profiler to see? Seems this question is one that can be answered by a bit of testing.

Comment: No it doesn't, a DbContext tracks changes so it knows what to commit. If it has no knowledge of any changes then what exactly would be the point of connecting to the database.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It uses EntityState to determine that there is nothing to commit and so does not waste resources.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx